# loading include file in emacs org-mode batch export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a shell script which exports several org files to latex; an example command is shown below:

```
emacs --batch \
--visit=file.org --funcall org-export-as-latex-batch
```

The first few lines of `file.org` are

```
#+TITLE: Titlename
#+INCLUDE: ./preamble.org
```

`preamble.org` has the following lines:

```
#+AUTHOR:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fullpage}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{parskip}
```

For some reason, `preamble.org` is not loaded when I execute in batch mode. It loads fine when I open the buffer and execute `M-x org-export-as-latex`. Any ideas what I need to do to have `preamble.org` load in batch mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
#+INCLUDE: ./preamble.org
```

doesn't work for me in both cases: manually and batch mode. I use

```
#+SETUPFILE: ./preamble.org
```

instead, and it works in batch mode too.